# Docker Container is unreachable outside localhost

Tags: docker

I'm running my mobile application backend server inside of a docker container (using Docker Desktop 2.4.0.0 for Windows). Suddenly my backend is unreachable outside localhost, so I can't test it from my phone physically. Works like a charm from the host, it even works if I try to reach it via local IP from the host, but if I use the same IP on my network, it's un-reachable. As far as I can tell, the only change that I made to my environment is accidentally updating Docker. Any help is appreciated. Kind regards.
Btw, when I run `docker ps` to check if the ports are forwarded correctly, the container that I want to reach is bound to 0.0.0.0.

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.20
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  web:
    image: tomcat:9.0.35
    container_name: web_app
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
      - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: did you provision the server from a cloud provider?

Comment: Nope, I'm running it on my personal machine. It's a Tomcat server.

Comment: Put some code that you use to run your docker images: `docker-compose` or `docker run`

Comment: @PandeyAmit Hi, thanks for answering, I've edited my question with the compose file I use, I haven't changed anything to it, last week it worked, it stopped after updating Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the Windows Firewall settings. One of the updates may have started obeying those settings instead of bypassing them. There was a [recent report of WSL2 bypassing the firewall](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-bypasses-the-windows-10-firewall/), so if you are using that and updated this patch Tuesday, that's a likely cause.

Comment: I can't believe it. This was the problem, deactivated Firewall and it worked. GG my friend.